# Galaxy Tab 3 producing continuous LightSensor error in LogCat

Tags: android, logging, eclipse

I am using a Galaxy Tab 3 as a test device for writing an android app. As such I'm interested in the output of the LogCat which is being filled with these error level messages.

The device itself appears to work correctly, apps which rely on the light sensor correctly respond to it and the number in the error itself goes down if the light sensor is obscured. If I wasn't using it to develop apps I wouldn't even be aware of the issue but I believe it is an issue with the device itself not my app: simply plugging the tab 3 into the computer and using Eclipse - ADT to look at the LogCat without any app running leads to these errors being shown.

I know I could filter the LogCat to ignore these errors but inconvenience aside; they concern me.

A sample of the log cat is below (it generates errors continuously). This is on verbose so it includes some debug level (`D/`) messages as well as the error level messages (`E/`).

How can I correct the device to no longer generate these errors.

```
06-11 10:08:45.789: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:45.992: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:46.195: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:46.398: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:46.601: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:46.804: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:47.007: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:47.210: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:47.414: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:47.617: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:47.820: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:48.023: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:48.039: D/dalvikvm(15201): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1947K, 17% free 16973K/20359K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 50ms
06-11 10:08:48.226: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:48.429: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 13
06-11 10:08:48.632: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 13
06-11 10:08:48.632: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(472): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
06-11 10:08:48.835: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:49.039: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:49.242: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:49.445: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 13
06-11 10:08:49.632: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(472): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
06-11 10:08:49.648: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 14
06-11 10:08:49.851: E/LightSensor(377): LightSensor::readEvents mPendingEvent.light = 13
```